# Laravel Voyager symlink(): No such file or directory CPanel

Tags: laravel, filesystems, symlink, voyager

I uploaded my project to cpanel. and I put the file in the public folder on home/user/public_html. and others in the home/user/laravel folder

in public_html I have a storage folder. 
but the file that I uploaded goes to home/user/laravel/storage
and symlink need folder public in home/user/laravel/

I don't really understand this filesystem

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

For Laravel 5.8

Step 1: Access the public directory of your project `public_html`

Step 2: Change the name to the folder called Storage by Storage2

Step 3: Open the index.php file

Step 4: Change `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` for `require __DIR__.'/../YOURFOLDERNAME/vendor/autoload.php';`

Step 5: Change `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` for `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../YOURFOLDERNAME/bootstrap/app.php';`

Step 6: **Now** you need to create a new file on `public_html` called `link.php`

Step 7: Add the following code to the file `link.php`

```
<?php 
symlink('/home/**server_directory**/**YOURFOLDERNAME**/storage/app/public','/home/**server_directory**/public_html/storage');
```

Step 8: Visit **yourwebsite.com/link.php**

**You will see a blank page**

Step 9: Go back to the administrative panel of Voyager and click on the "Fix it" button

Step 10: Delete link.php file from your server.

This worked for me, I hope it works for you too. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that I didn't have a "public" folder in the original "storage" folder like: "storage / app / public"